# How to find list of curated datasets

Tags: curated-data

How does one find a list of all curated datasets in *Mathematica*?  For instance, I was seeking representative reflection spectra of various types of fruit, and searched through the entity **foods**, but could not find any spectra.  I tried **natural language** input, but failed, not knowing whether my query was wrong or the dataset did not exist.  Likewise for atomic spectra and several other possible datasets, such as fine art paintings, automobiles, and so forth.  Is there any way besides hunting through `EntityValues[]`?

Answer (score 4):

I think `EntityValue` is more or less it, so this is not really an answer. However, I sometimes find fooling around with `InputForm` and the natural language interface useful. Here is an example.

I give `InputForm` that the argument the natural language interface returns after I type in the string "art paintings" and I get

[image: interp]

That tells me something about how I should do queries on famous paintings.

This is helpful when it works, but it doesn't always. I find the natural language interface quirky and using it can often be frustrating.

Comment: Thanks.  I find the natural language interface occasionally useful when I've forgotten an obscure syntax, enter the natural language query and receive the *Mathematica* function call.  As for curated databases...  Suppose I wanted the optical reflectance spectrum of human skin.  How would I search, and how would I know that (apparently) this is *not* in any curated databases?  So +1 for you (but still no check).

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. I didn't expect an acceptance. This answer only offers a crutch, not a cure. I don't think there is a cure. The issue you are raising is one of several that contribute to making it a pain to use curated data.